# Query to check the difference of tables in two warehouses

Tags: mysql

I have two environments (production and development)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'production';
```

Qty of tables in production 300

After to install a new feature in development appeared more tables

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'development';
```

Qty of tables in development 303

I wonder if there is a Query (no extencion like [MySQLdiff](http://www.mysqldiff.org/) ) to check what are the tables that have been added, i mean the 3 tables that are in development but not in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using LEFT JOIN to get a diff of two temporary tables, namely one with your production scheme tables and one with your development scheme tables:

```
SELECT table_name_development FROM
  (SELECT table_name AS table_name_development FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'development') AS d
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT table_name AS table_name_production FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'production') AS p
ON table_name_development=table_name_production
WHERE table_name_production IS NULL;
```

Comment: The query works but instead of return the table name , returns null values

Comment: It should read SELECT table_name_development of course, as these are the entries you where looking for. Sorry about that, I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL workbench has an utility called [mysqldbcompare](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.3/en/mysqldbcompare.html), it compares the differences between two databases.
The diff output could be a csv or simply can be sql statements, so you can run those DMLs to your development environment.

The SQL output would be complete DML statements(CREATE TABLE/INSERT STATEMENTS) so as your target database look alike as source.

Abstractly something like this:

```
$ mysqldbcompare --server1=root:root@localhost \
    --server2=root:root@localhost db1:db2 --changes-for=server1 -a \
    --difftype=sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure use a left join   This will return the data from information_Schema listing the tables in the development schema not in the production schema.

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables A
LEFT JOIN information_Schema.tables B
  on A.Table_Name = B.Table_Name
  and B.table_Schema = 'production'
  and A.Table_Schema = 'development'
Where B.Table_Schema is null
```

Comment: I tried but the output was Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'B.TableName' in 'on clause'

Comment: had a typo should have been b.table_name.